# Unable to upload image data to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload image data to S3 like this in my spring-boot application:

```
String key = "destination/9229e871-3431-473d-bgaf-7ae52f23c272/time/1221394409192443/type/imageoverview/label/Car.jpeg";
ObjectMetadata metaData = new ObjectMetadata();
metaData.setContentLength(result.getHeaders().getContentLength());
metaData.setContentType(result.getHeaders().getContentType().getType()+"/"+
                    result.getHeaders().getContentType().getSubtype());
s3Client.putObject("my-bucket", key, new ByteArrayInputStream(result.getBody()), metaData);
```

result is response from another remote service and contains image data.

With this, I get error:

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch...
```

I checked [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html), and key seems to follow all rules. Signing method must not be the cause as I can upload files to another bucket and I create AmazonS3 instance same way in both cases.

One thing to note is that folder structure is not already there in s3. I assume that when not found, S3 would create it. My objective is to create folders dynamically based on image id and timestamp(both passed as parts of key)

So what am I missing here?

Comment: Got it working.Issue is with metaData.setContentLength(result.getHeaders().getContentLength());
Content length must be set to should be result.getBody().length instead.

Comment: You are welcome to add your own Answer to the Question.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working.Issue is with:

```
metaData.setContentLength(result.getHeaders().getContentLength());
```

It must be:

```
metaData.setContentLength(result.getBody().length);
```